# VMware Workstation VMNet interfaces disappear after reboot

Tags: 16.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

Running Ubuntu Desktop LTS 16.04 and Vmware workstation 12.5.2.  After I install Vmware, i launch Vmware with `sudo vmware`. I then create VMNet interfaces with the Virtual Network Editor.  After I reboot Ubuntu, the VMNet interfaces I created are gone.  However, the Vmnet1 and Vmnet8 interfaces that were created during the VMWare installation are visible. I have added `chmod a+rw /dev/vmnet*` to the */etc/init.d/vmware*, although that is to allow promiscuous mode on the VMNet interfaces.

I am thinking this is some sort of permissions issue, but I don't really know.  Anyone seen this before - VMNet interfaces created in Vmware Workstation disappear after reboot?

Thanks much

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run `sudo systemctl restart vmware`?  If all works well the vmnet interfaces will be made again with this, but if it errors we need that info.

Comment: i have since downloaded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but exact same issue occurs.  Here is output, first, of "service vmware ubuntu":

Comment: first, "service vmware ubuntu": 
/etc/init.d$ sudo service vmware restart
Stopping VMware services:VMware Authentication Daemon    doneVM communication interface socket family  doneVirtual machine communication interface  done
Virtual machine monitor    done
Blocking file system    done
Starting VMware services:
Virtual machine monitor      done
Virtual machine communication interface   done
 VM communication interface socket family   done
Blocking file system    done
Virtual ethernet     failed
VMware Authentication Daemon   done

Comment: actually, i downgraded to ubuntu 14.04 in between my original post and now and systemctrl does not exist on 14.0.4.  this noob was unawares that this would be the case.  is there a 14.04 command to get the information you are asking?

Comment: a couple of relevenat lines from Vmnetlib log file after i issued sudo service vmware start:  Subnet on vmnet2 is no longer available for usage, please run the network editor to reconfigure different subnet
Failed to start some/all services
Jan 28 18:52:54 VNL_Load - LOG_ERR logged
Jan 28 18:52:54 VNL_Load - LOG_WRN logged
Jan 28 18:52:54 VNL_Load - LOG_OK logged
Jan 28 18:52:54 VNL_Load - Successfully initialized Vnetlib
i also have no idea how to provide all the info when the num of chars allowed in comment is so small.